# yahoo place finder api response xml display

Tags: xml, api, xmlhttprequest, xslt

Im here trying to work with yahoo place finder api.
I want to get the latitude and longitude of a particular location given name of place.
When i use place finder api i get the response text in xml and im trying to style it with Xslt.

My problem:

```
http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=701+First+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA&appid=myapiid
```

is the get request where i get an xml as response which i have to style with xslt and display.

i have a code here which does that.I believe it is right .I always get a blank page

```
    <html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=701+First+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA&appid=MYAPIKEY");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("latitude.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Latitude Longitute finder</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Latitude</th>
      <th>Longitude</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Result/latitude"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Result/longitute"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update from link: Yahoo response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResultSet version="1.0">
    <Error>0</Error>
    <ErrorMessage>No error</ErrorMessage>
    <Locale>us_US</Locale>
    <Quality>87</Quality>
    <Found>1</Found>
    <Result>
        <quality>87</quality>
        <latitude>37.416275</latitude>
        <longitude>-122.025092</longitude>
        <offsetlat>37.416397</offsetlat>
        <offsetlon>-122.025055</offsetlon>
        <radius>500</radius>
        <name></name>
        <line1>701 1st Ave</line1>
        <line2>Sunnyvale, CA  94089-1019</line2>
        <line3></line3>
        <line4>United States</line4>
        <house>701</house>
        <street>1st Ave</street>
        <xstreet></xstreet>
        <unittype></unittype>
        <unit></unit>
        <postal>94089-1019</postal>
        <neighborhood></neighborhood>
        <city>Sunnyvale</city>
        <county>Santa Clara County</county>
        <state>California</state>
        <country>United States</country>
        <countrycode>US</countrycode>
        <statecode>CA</statecode>
        <countycode></countycode>
        <uzip>94089</uzip>
        <hash>DDAD1896CC0CDC41</hash>
        <woeid>12797150</woeid>
        <woetype>11</woetype>
    </Result>
</ResultSet>
<!-- gws30.maps.re3.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Wed Jan 12 16:29:58 PST 2011 -->
```

Comment: There isn't any question asked. If the question is "whether it is right or wrong" to always get a blank page, I guess that the answer is: It is wrong.

Comment: Thnx i edited the question.I believe it is right.I just need somehelp

Answer (score 2):

Bobby,

Your stylesheet will always output some HTML, at least a table, even if the input XML is wrong or missing. If you're not even getting a table, then the problem is not that the input XML is wrong or missing; rather something is wrong with loading or applying the XSLT stylesheet. Make sure the URL to the stylesheet is correct. You have a relative URL ("latitude.xsl"), so make sure the stylesheet is accessible at the URL "latitude.xsl" relative to the URL of the page you are accessing (not the yahooapis page).

You can also try a test/alert after the `xsl=loadXMLDoc("latitude.xsl");` to make sure the stylesheet loaded.

(Also, 'longitude' is misspelled in your stylesheet, but that problem won't show up until you are loading the stylesheet successfully.)

Comment: I think my relative url is correct.I have both the html file and xsl style sheet in  a same location(i have them on my desktop).So i think it should be right.I tried alert too but i wasnt getting alert.

Comment: @bobby: If you aren't getting any alert at all, the relevant code section is not being exercised. Please show the code for your alert, and tell what browser you are using. Another possibility is that your Ajax call is failing, so your displayResult() function is not getting called.

Comment: I did this after loadXMLDoc..!!!                xsl=loadXMLDoc("latitude.xsl");
alert("successful");   Im using firefox 3.6

Comment: hhey displayresult function is executing but if i keeep alert before xml=loadXMLDoc("http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=701+First+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA&appid=yahooid");

Comment: I think xml=loadXMLDoc("call to yahoo api is not working"); If i keep alert between call to api and call to style sheet ..there is no alert.but when i paste the yahoo api url in browser then it displays a XML document

Comment: When i paste this url in browser and press enter it displays xml document ..so the yahoo api call is correct...   http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=701+First+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA&appid=MYAPPID

Comment: I got it my call to api dosent work..I figured out using firebug.      
GET http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=701+First+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA&appid=applicationnid
 
200 OK
  392ms                                                 Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Users/bobby/Desktop/a.html :: loadXMLDoc :: line 15" data: no]

Comment: I think the problem is here : https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control               Im unable to figure it out

Comment: @bobby, what makes you think the problem is with http access control? Also, lack of punctuation and capitalization in your comments makes them pretty hard to read. I'm not inclined to put in much more effort if you aren't.

Comment: Im sorry if u feel that way...                                    Im unable to edit comments now..                                    I used firebug to check xmlHttprequest ..                          I posted it as a seperate question with error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673369/understanding-xmlhttpresponse-error

Comment: I think the problem is with Http Access control is that, when wanted to get the appid from yahoo place finder it asked me for the url where il be using the application.then i gave a url .Now when i read the mozilla http access control,when making a call from a url[Im opening it from my desktop not from the url i entered when registering for yahoo place api]So i think the yahoo checking it with the url i entered during the time of registration and it is not granting access from other url. I also have a doubt that this is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

With the input source is clear that you need to change the pattern from

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

To

```
<xsl:template match="/ResultSet">
```