# xsltProcessor.importStylesheet error

Tags: xml, ajax, xslt

Im trying to work with following code i getting this error at **xsltProcessor.importStylesheet**

Error when i removed: `xhttp.send(null);`

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIXSLTProcessor.importStylesheet]"  nsresult: "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Users/bobby/Desktop/geocoding.html :: displayResult :: line 35"  data: no]

Line 0
```

Error when i have: `xhttp.send(null);`

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Users/bobby/Desktop/geocoding.html :: loadXMLDoc :: line 16"  data: no]

Line 0
```

My html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);

return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{ 
xml=loadXMLDoc("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false");
alert("successful call to xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("latitude.xsl");
alert("successful applying style sheet");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

My Xslt style sheet as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Latitude Longitute finder</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Latitude</th>
      <th>Longitude</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="GeocodeResponse/result/type"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="GeocodeResponse/result/address_component/long_name"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="GeocodeResponse/result/address_component/short_name"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [yahoo place finder api response xml display ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670609/yahoo-place-finder-api-response-xml-display)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well unless your HTML document with the script is hosted on http://maps.googleapis.com/ your script is not allowed to load documents with XMLHttpRequest from that origin, due to the same origin policy in place for client-side code in browsers. So I would expect a browser like Mozilla to throw an exception on the send call if you are trying to load data from http://maps.googleapis.com/.
As for the error on the importStylesheet, consider to show a minimal but complete stylesheet allowing us to reproduce the error. Or better yet, first run the stylesheet outside of the browser through an XSLT 1.0 processor which gives you better error messages, I suspect there is simply a problem in the stylesheet.

Comment: Martin i have posted my xslt sheet above.

Comment: hhey is there other way for my code to work.I know the same origin policy but wasnt sure of it.Now i dont know where to start from to make my code to work.should i use server-side scripting.Im confused

Comment: That stylesheet is fine as far as I can tell and I used a local copy here with Firefox 3.6 and importStylesheet without getting an error. As far as accessing that data, indeed you either need to use server-side programming to load the XML data or you need to check whether there is any Javascript API exposed you can use as doing `<script src="http://example.com/script.js?callback=foo"></script>` is not subject to the same origin policy.

Comment: This is a good catch! Consider to post this is the original question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670609/yahoo-place-finder-api-response-xml-display because this is a duplicate